# Room Database: Livedata observer more than actual row size

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i just have one row in Room database , but when i read it, i get two row with one value.
i don't know that is how room database work or i missing something.

and i wish everyone have a nice day!

FriendModel

```
@Entity(tableName = "friend_table")
class FriendModel
    : Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    var _id: String = ""
    ...
}
```

DAO interface

```
@Dao
interface FriendDAO {
    ...
    @Query("select _id from friend_table")
    fun readRoomIdFriendsDAO() : LiveData<List<String>>
}
```

Repository

```
class UserRepository(private val userAPI: UserAPI, context : Context) {
    private val userDAO : UserDAO
    private val friendDAO : FriendDAO
    init {
        val userDatabase: UserRoomDatabase = UserRoomDatabase.getInstance(context)
        val friendDatabase: FriendRoomDatabase = FriendRoomDatabase.getInstance(context)

        userDAO = userDatabase.getUserDao()
        friendDAO = friendDatabase.getFriendDao()
    }
    ...
    fun readRoomIdFriendsDAO() : LiveData<List<String>> = friendDAO.readRoomIdFriendsDAO()
    
}
```

ViewModel

```
class UserViewModel(private val userRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
      ...
      fun readRoomIdFriendsDAO() : LiveData<List<String>> = userRepository.readRoomIdFriendsDAO()
}
```

and i use it in MainActivity

```
viewModel.readRoomIdFriendsDAO().observe(this,{ listRoomId ->
            if(listRoomId!=null && listRoomId.isNotEmpty()){
                for(item in listRoomId){
                    Log.e(TAG, "RoomId: $listRoomId")
                }
            }
        })
```

and this is what i get

```
E/Log: RoomId: [IZnIP4srwDZiB1foauiZF6R60RF3]
...
E/Log: RoomId: [IZnIP4srwDZiB1foauiZF6R60RF3]
```

Comment: Check if the method which is the parent to the observer is being called twice. A bit more code from MainActivity will help us understand better.

Comment: oh i understood, i'll check MainActivity, my MainActivity so mess if i put all code seem not well. thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

May be you called `readRoomIdFriendsDAO()` twice. Android source not wrong in this case

Comment: Please share your answer in English.